# Как создать мультиязычный сайт на MODx, где у каждого языка будут свои статьи (не перевод одинаковых статей)?

Tags: modx, babel

Необходимо создать мультиязычный сайт (русский, английский, кыргызский), где у каждого языка будут свои статьи (не перевод одинаковых статей).

Делал по этому [уроку](http://www.r-team.com.ua/blog/modx/kak_realizovat_multiyazychnost_dlya_saytov_na_ModX_REVO), создал контексты, установил babel.

Вопросы:

1. как сделать контекст для киргизского языка? просто поставить `culturekey=kg`?
2. как осуществляется перевод блоков в чанках, например, «комментарии» или кнопок «вход»? это нужно создавать свои чанки для новых контекстов? или можно где-то хранить эти слова?
3. как контролировать, какие ресурсы выводить через pdoresources (getresources)? вносить id и одного и другого и третьего контекста?
4. для контекста web — страницы имеют вид mywebsite.ru/category/article, а для контекста en — `mywebsite.ru/en/INDEX/category/article`. как убрать этот index, при перехода на `mywebsite.ru/en/` — показывает 503 ошибку. как ее исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вот именно,что нужно создать контекст: `Настройки(значок шестеренки) -> "Контексты" -> "создать новый"`.
   И у нового контекста заполняете все поля по аналогии с английским.
2. Этот перевод нужно делать через словари - для каждого языка нужно создавать свой набор слов: `Настройки(значок шестеренки) -> "управление словарями" -> "создать запись"`
3. На вскидку переключение происходит автоматически. За включением нового стартового id для ваших сниппетов вывода информации должен следить спец.плагин для переключения контекста. Он пишется отдельно.
4. Вы что-то нахимичили с настройками у babel, либо не правильно написали плагин для переключения контекста,либо не настроили .htaccess

*Помидорами прошу не закидывать,делал мультиязычность порядка 1.5 лет назад.
Если с моих слов ничего не понятно,кину пару ссылок с туториалами по настройке babel на modx revo.*